# Native way to get all nth-position elements in all subarrays of a 2D array

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a native function that works like `combine_subarrays` below?

```
$foo = array(
   array(1,2,3),
   array(4,5,6),
   array(7,8,9)
);

$n = 1;   // desired element's position in each subarray 
$bar = combine_subarrays($foo, $n);

// Result: $bar is array of all elements in 1st positions - [2,5,8]
```

Right now, I foreach through $foo and push the $nth element onto a new array that is then returned. If there's a native way to do it, it would be better.

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution with global reference to $n would be:

```
$n = 1;
$bar = array_map(function($item) { 
        global $n; 
        return $item[$n]; 
    }, 
    $foo);
```

And the result is:

```
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 5 [2] => 8 )
```

Comment: if you already have an anonymous function, better use the closure feature instead of global vars `array_map(function($item) use(&$n)`

Answer (score 1):

There is no function that does *exactly* that but several ways to use the array functions instead of writing a loop. For example [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/array-reduce)*:

```
$bar = array_reduce($foo, function(&$result, $item) use ($n) {
    $result[] = $item[$n]
});
```

**[`array_map`](http://php.net/array-map) is probably the better choice, it also preserves the original keys. See [answer by @zeldi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507015/native-way-to-get-all-nth-position-elements-in-all-subarrays-of-a-2d-array/15100738#15100738)*